# $client->get() in Guzzle failing to return JSON

Tags: php, guzzle

```
// https://api.xivdb.com/character/17803411 <-- fail
// https://api.xivdb.com/character/1395894 <-- success
function GetCharacter( $url )
{
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

    $res = $client->get( $url );

    echo $res->getStatusCode();
    exit();


    return json_decode( $res->getBody(), true );
}
```

In the above code, when I use the successful $url, my code works and I get the status code 200. However, when I use the $url that fails, I just get the generic

> 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you
>   are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Now, the return for the fail $url, when going directly to it is:

> { code: 404, error: "The character you are looking for could not be
>   found. The character may still be being processed or the XIVSync
>   service has gone down." }

My question is, why the $client->get() returns the JSON from the successful $url, but just flat fails on the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guzzle will trigger an exception if the response is not 200. That's why you see the 500 error on your side.

You will have to catch this error like this.

```
try {
    $res = $client->get($url);
}
catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
    // error.
}
```

Comment: Does it work now? If so, can you accept the answer, please :)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to request those endpoints.

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;

$client = new Client();

$validApiEndpoint = 'https://api.xivdb.com/character/1395894';
$invalidApiEndpoint = 'https://api.xivdb.com/character/17803411';

try {
    $response = $client->get($invalidApiEndpoint);

    echo $response->getStatusCode();
} catch (ClientException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Guzzle is simply throwing an exception, because of the status code being not 200 from the request to `$invalidApiEndpont`.

You should create some kind of adapter class using **Adapter Pattern** to prevent exceptions from being thrown directly if this is a problem in your application. Using Guzzle client directly is a bad idea.

If you have a question about Adapter Pattern implementation in your case, I can describe it for you.